# How to show $n\sum_{i=1}^n {x_i^2} \ge (\sum_{i=1}^n{x_i})^2$

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

How can I show that $n\sum_{i=1}^n {x_i^2} \ge (\sum_{i=1}^n{x_i})^2$ for any natural number $n$ and $x_i \in\mathbb{R}?$ I assume there is something about Cauchy-Schwarz and induction, but I really don't see it.

Comment: If the sum $\sum x_i$ is less than $\frac{1}{n}$ then the statement is false

Comment: False, let $x_i=\frac1{2n^2}$

Comment: Agh I missed a squared!

Comment: @heropup How does this account for my counterexample $x_1=-x_2=1$?

Comment: I just realize I have the inequality flipped. This is a mess.

Comment: @Anonymous You don't have the inequality flipped. The flipped version is the regular cauchy schwarz inequality, and doesn't have an $n$.

Comment: I updated it... I don't know the procedure for screw ups like this, I'm sorry.

Comment: Just keep updating, you're fine.

Comment: I think that's the question.

Comment: duplicate? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/748043/positivity-of-a-function-in-mathbbrn

Comment: @user2345215 Even if it is a duplicate or special case of that one, this one is much more concise and to the point than that one (also it's been changed several times so that I don't think it is still a duplicate).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $x_i\ge0$ for each $i$, $x_i\le\sum_{k=1}^nx_k$ and $x_i^2\le(\sum_{k=1}^nx_k)^2$ for each $i$, so

$$\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2\le\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\sum_{k=1}^nx_k\right)^2=n\left(\sum_{k=1}^nx_k\right)^2$$

The updated version follows from the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, with $y_i=1$ in:
$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^nx_iy_i\right)^2\le\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2\sum_{i=1}^ny_i^2$$
to yield 
$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^nx_i\right)^2\le\sum_{i=1}^ny_i^2\cdot n$$

Comment: I think it's just $x_i \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: In that case it's not true; take $x_1=-x_2=1$ and $n=2$.

Comment: Oh I see. Jeez. I'm sorry.

Comment: You mean x, I think? :P

Comment: Thank you! It's beautiful!

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
Lets $\ds{\vec{\alpha} = \overbrace{\pars{1,1,\ldots,1}}^{\ds{n\,\,\,\,\, 1'\mbox{s}}}\ \mbox{and}\ \vec{r}\equiv\pars{x_{1},x_{2},\ldots,x_{n}}}$:

> \begin{align}
> \pars{\vec{r}\cdot\vec{\alpha}}^{2} &\leq r^{2}\alpha^{2}\tag{1}
> \\[3mm]\vec{r}\cdot\vec{\alpha} =\sum_{i = 1}^{n}x_{i}\,,\qquad
> r^{2} &= \sum_{i = 1}^{n}x_{i}^{2}\,,\qquad \alpha^{2} = \sum_{i = 1}^{n}1^{2}=n
> \end{align}

$$\color{#00f}{\large%
n\sum_{i = 1}^{n}x_{i}^{2} \geq \pars{\sum_{i = 1}^{n}x_{i}}^{2}}
$$

> $\pars{1}$ arises from $\ds{\pars{~\mbox{with}\ \lambda \in {\mathbb R}~}}$:
>   $$
> 0\leq\pars{\vec{r} + \lambda\vec{\alpha}}^{2} = \alpha^{2}\lambda^{2}
> +2\vec{r}\cdot\vec{\alpha}\,\lambda + r^{2}\
> \imp\ \pars{2\vec{r}\cdot\vec{\alpha}}^{2} - 4\alpha^{2}r^{2}\leq 0\
> \imp\ \pars{\vec{r}\cdot\vec{\alpha}}^{2} \leq \alpha^{2}r^{2}
> $$

Answer (score 0):

The statement is false. Take $x_1 = \dfrac{1}{2}$, and $n = 1$.

Comment: I'm sorry, please look once more I had a typo!

Answer (score 0):

This is a special case of [Chebyshev's sum inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_sum_inequality) for $a_i=b_i$.

Answer (score 0):

This question is equivalent to proving that the following quadratic form is positive semidefinite：
$$
f(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n) = n\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2-\left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right)^2
$$

if you can notice the following equation, then we can easily proof the answer.

$$
\begin{aligned}
f\left(x_{1}, x_{2}, \cdots, x_{n}\right) &=n \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i}^{2}-\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i}\right)^{2} =\sum_{i<j}\left(x_{i}-x_{j}\right)^{2} \ge 0
\end{aligned}
$$

$$
\begin{aligned}
&\quad  \,\,\, n \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i}^{2}-\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i}\right)^{2} \\
&=n \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i}^{2}-\left(\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2+2\sum_{i<j}x_ix_j\right)\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n(n-1)x_i^2 - 2\sum_{i<j}x_ix_j
\end{aligned}
$$

$$
\begin{aligned}
&\sum_{i<j} \left(x_i-x_j\right)^2\\
=&\sum_{i<j}\left(x_i^2 -2x_ix_j + x_j^2\right)\\
=&\sum_{i<j}(x_i^2+x_j^2)-2\sum_{i<j}x_ix_j\\
=&\sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{i=1}^{j-1}x_i^2 +\sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{i=1}^{j-1}x_j^2 -2\sum_{i<j}x_ix_j\\
=&\sum_{i=1}^n(n-1)x_i^2 - 2\sum_{i<j}x_ix_j 
\end{aligned}
$$